# Deconstruct generic type which made from another generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Apologies if the question title is vague. Not sure how to best describe this

Lets say I have this generic interface

```
interface IPaginatedResponse<T> {
    results: T[],
    page: number,
    count: number
}
```

and I have this concrete type

```
type PaginatedUsers = IPaginatedResponse<User>
```

Now I want to create a function which takes in any `type` that is a concrete type of `IPaginatedResponse`

```
// Invalid syntax

const myFn = <IPaginatedResponse<T>>() => {
 ...
 // Do something with T
}
```

So that I can catch typing errors

```
myFn<PaginatedUsers>()  // OK
myFn<User>()            // Fails
```

The above is pseudocode.

Comment: I believe you'll want to use `infer` (`<T extends IPaginatedResponse<infer R>>`) and then you can reference `R`.

Comment: @willis hmm, I tried that but ts complains that "'infer' declarations are only permitted in the 'extends' clause of a conditional type. ts(1338)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function takes any `IPaginatedResponse`, you'll want your function to take `<T extends IPaginatedResponse<any>>`. To get access to the internal type, you can use the `infer` keyword to create a generic helper to extract the type of whatever you're paginating:

```js
type GetPaginatedType<T extends IPaginatedResponse<any>> = T extends IPaginatedResponse<infer R> ? R : never;
```

You can then use that helper to grab the type within your function (or add it to your return statement).

```js
type User = "user"
interface IPaginatedResponse<T> {
    results: T[],
    page: number,
    count: number
}
type PaginatedUsers = IPaginatedResponse<User>
type GetPaginatedType<T> = T extends IPaginatedResponse<infer R> ? R : never;
// this works
const user: GetPaginatedType<PaginatedUsers> = "user";

// this doesn't
const notUser: GetPaginatedType<PaginatedUsers> = "notuser";

const myFn = <T extends IPaginatedResponse<any>>() => {
  type MyInternalType = GetPaginatedType<T>;
}

myFn<PaginatedUsers>();
// this correctly errors
myFn<User>();
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFARAVwY9AoPASwDtgkAzAQwGNoBJABUoHMTKyATAJQjjAHtiCADwAVAHxQA3nihyoiXpgA2wOAC4oogNoBdADSz5YFhE3FMAWwBGSQ-KjV+mUuau3EeAL55QkKEysxOwQHPBIcKhQjCxsnDx8giLhiOK+4NAA4hDAgXGhohlikmiiUBAAHmTEHJExQSHcvAJCEMIk5EhQXJIA-N1Q5hAAbkgA3HgA9JNQwAAWhJEA7vyIANZweE5CwFDYSJrZubHBnIWQwnmnoSlwJRj7uBNTM-OLUBz8vMQA5MBbSV2xH4wBShxyV0a5zakM4t3u6GBwEe6GefmgogWcDocAAciMumgjrCCkUUuJnts4LtLCAAGLEKJicpVCA1OokpqJVrCSjEEDicQACgAlKhJDI5OioABZEB0UhIYLKaFRYknKFFCQTHx4WkMy4auE4O6iibTWZYxyrRTUYDKEDlRCIVabfXEYTks14IA)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `extends`

```
<T extends IPaginatedResponse<any>>
```